# Upgrade error: while removing kernel

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel

When trying to install or upgrade system - removing kernel raises error, something about grub. Grub working fine and I see menu when booting.
May be some additional information should be provided?

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic
...
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic (4.15.0-52.56) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-52-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2:
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... 

Could not find /boot/grub/menu.lst file. Would you like /boot/grub/menu.lst generated for you? (y/N) /usr/sbin/update-grub-legacy-ec2: line 1101: read: read error: 0: Bad file descriptor
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


leonid@DevSSD:~$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02-2ubuntu8.13
leonid@DevSSD:~$ uname -r
4.15.0-54-generic
```

Update:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep grub
ii  grub-common                           2.02-2ubuntu8.13                             amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
ii  grub-efi-amd64                        2.02-2ubuntu8.13                             amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-bin                    2.02-2ubuntu8.13                             amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 binaries)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-signed                 1.93.14+2.02-2ubuntu8.13                     amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version, signed)
ii  grub-legacy-ec2                       1:1                                          all          Handles update-grub for ec2 instances
ii  grub2-common                          2.02-2ubuntu8.13                             amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)
```

Update:
Boot is UEFI and I used to repaired grub once, with BootRepair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist of all please make like @heynnema  mentioned a filesystmcheck.

```
sudo dpkg -P grub-legacy-ec2
```

when the command  is not working.

```
sudo mv /etc/kernel/postrm.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 $HOME
```

in both cases run afterwards

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better check out your file system first... you may have some corruption there...

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`